# Using System.AddIn's FrameworkElementAdapters in background threads

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, add-in

Without getting too much into the "why" I need to do this, here is my situation. I need to create an INativeHandleContract to pass a UserControl over an AppDomain boundary, from a new AppDomain into the main AppDomain, where it is then added to a StackPanel. But I am also trying to do this in a different thread. I ran in to a situation where it appears the UserControl is being added correctly if this all runs in the same thread. If I add the UserControl to the StackPanel from a separate thread, it seems to get added but nothing appears on screen. So I boiled this down to the following code and found where the difference is. First the working code:

```
private void AddTestControlInNewThread()
{
    System.Threading.Thread t = new System.Threading.Thread(AddTestControl);
    t.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
    t.Start();
}

private void AddTestControl()
{
    INativeHandleContract contract;
    FrameworkElement fe;

    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        contract = FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter(new Label() { Content = DateTime.Now.ToString() });
        fe = FrameworkElementAdapters.ContractToViewAdapter(contract);
        parentStackPanel.Children.Add(fe);

    }), null);
}
```

That works just fine, however, in my scenario, I cannot create the "contract" inside of the Dispatcher.Invoke call. So I moved it to just outside of that and that's where thing stop working. Here is the difference in code:

```
private void AddTestControl()
{
    INativeHandleContract contract;
    FrameworkElement fe;

    contract = FrameworkElementAdapters.ViewToContractAdapter(new Label() { Content = DateTime.Now.ToString() });

    Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => 
    {

        fe = FrameworkElementAdapters.ContractToViewAdapter(contract);
        parentStackPanel.Children.Add(fe);

    }), null);
}
```

Can anyone shine some light on why the user control would not show up, even if it does get added to the parentStackPanel's Children collection successfully? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd love to know the why behind your unique situation. I'm assuming that the Dispatcher is associated with the same thread on which `parentStackPanel` is created. WPF controls have thread-affinity and all of them must be modified from the same thread. You are constructing a `Label` object which in your first example, is constructed in the same thread as the `StackPanel` which is good. In your second example, it is constructed on a different thread which is most likely why the code is not working. Attach with a debugger and you ought to catch some sort of exception being thrown.

Comment: Great catch. I tried it with the actual label and did get a "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it." That changes my question then. I wonder if it's possible to create a control on a background thread and add it to a control on the main thread.

Comment: You can't create the UIElement from another thread. The classes are usually very cheap to create. If the underlying data that you intend to pass to the UIElement is expensive or time consuming to compute, just perform that computation on the background thread and pass the result to the UI thread to construct the object.

Comment: Yep. So it appears. I wish there was a way to wrap the user control so that it could be added as a child from another thread.

Comment: As for that "why", I'm working on a PRISM like framework that loads its modules inside of separate AppDomains. I'm adding some specialized functionality that we use at the company I work for. I was hoping to separate all functionality of the module into it's own thread to mitigate any influence one module might have on another or on the shell. I didn't want to leave that strictly to the designer of the module (relaying on them for good thread usage).